# Any Jquery gallery to show image and on hover show description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any Jquery plugin available where I can put in my images in HTML and on hover it would show some animation and description coming from the bottom of the image to cover about half the image.

I've seen that on some websites but I don't really know the plugin name. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty, though you might have to do a little coding yourself. Just go to google and type "jquery image gallery" and you will have plenty of choices. Do a little research yourself, try to implement one that seems decent and if you run into problems come back and ask for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these galleries:

1. http://codecanyon.net/item/hoveralls-v13/full_screen_preview/1367456
2. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
3. http://nivozoom.dev7studios.com/

I guess that the first one (with the rats demo) will fit your needs best.